# MA Access 2010 VBA code outputs in RUN cmd in macro but not off form button

Tags: vba, ms-access

The following is called from a MS Access 2010 macro. I can use the macro RUN command to run the routine and it correctly creates and stores a file of data in the "c:\EOW" folder.
When I run the macro from a button on a form, it appears to do exactly the same thing and exits as the macro RUN does but there is no file output as there is with the macro RUN method.
Any advice appreciated.

Scott

Call in macro is "ExportQueryToTxt("MYOBWklyInvoices","c:\EOW\MYOBWklyInvoices.txt",1,",")"
and the VBA function is below;

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function ExportQueryToTxt(ByVal DataSource As String, _
                     ByVal FileName As String, _
                     Optional DocIDIndex As Long = 0, _
                     Optional ByVal ListSeparator As String = ",")

' See  http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-access/1664379-automatically-adding-blank-lines-text-file.html
'
' SMW NOTE: definitely does not work with a query with a PARAMETER in it
'           Does work if make a table from query and use it
' DataSource:    Name of a table, a SELECT query or a SELECT SQL statement.
'                In any case, the rowset must be sorted on the DocIDIndex column.

' FileName:      Name of the output file that will receive the exported rows.

' DocIDIndex:    Ordinal position of the column in the rowset
'                that contains the document ID (default = 0 --> first column).

' ListSeparator: Character used to separate the different columns of data
'                in the text output file (default = ",")
'
' Example of call: ExportQueryToTxt "Qry_Export", "c:\export.txt", 1, ";"
'
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    Dim intHandle As Integer
    Dim strLine As String
    Dim varDocID As Variant

    intHandle = FreeFile
    Open FileName For Output As #intHandle   ' Use 'For Append' to add lines to an existing file, if any.
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    ' MsgBox ("Started")
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(DataSource)

    ' SMW load first line with MYOB field names + input week number parameter
    strLine = ""
    strLine = "Ignore,Invoice,Customer PO,Description,Account,Amount,Inc Tax,Supplier,Journal Memo,SP First Name,Tax Code,GST Amount,Category,CardID"
    Print #intHandle, strLine
    strLine = ""
    ' End SMW
    With rst
        If Not .EOF Then
        ' note that following will group anything wth same invoice or similar number togeher in
        ' sequential rows then inject a blank row when the invoice number changes
        varDocID = rst.Fields(DocIDIndex).Value
            Do Until .EOF
                For Each fld In rst.Fields
                    If Len(strLine) > 0 Then strLine = strLine & ListSeparator
                    strLine = strLine & fld.Value
                Next
                If rst.Fields(DocIDIndex).Value <> varDocID Then strLine = vbNewLine & strLine
                Print #intHandle, strLine
                strLine = ""
                varDocID = rst.Fields(DocIDIndex).Value
                .MoveNext
            Loop
        End If
        .Close
    End With
    Set rst = Nothing
    Close #intHandle
    ' SMW added to advise when done
    ' MsgBox ("Finished making invoices")

End Function
```

Comment: Put some Debug.Print "whatever" in you code to see what line are executing, and which ones aren't.

Comment: I have tried to do that but none are displayed when the macro runs from a control button.  They are displayed when I manualy run the macro. I don't know much about running VBA I am sorry to say so might not be using debug correctly.

Comment: If none are displayed when run from the button, it sounds like the function is never called. You're going to dig to find out where it's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to involve a Macro, and doing so won't generally produce helpful error messages. (There might be a problem with the nested quotes.)

Display the Property Sheet for the Button, find the On Click event and type the following directly it that row:

```
=ExportQueryToTxt("MYOBWklyInvoices","c:\EOW\MYOBWklyInvoices.txt",1,",")
```

Notice the equal-sign is required, and the surrounding quotes are no longer necessary.

Add a simple `MsgBox` to the function so that you can prove that it is running.